# how to parse and convert 'Jan 15 2019 6:57PM' to timestamp format in snowflake

Tags: timestamp, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, datetime-conversion

How can I convert a string in the format 'Jan 15 2019 6:57PM' to a proper timestamp format in snowflake.

It is throwing error as cannot parse timestamp 'Jan 15 2019 6:57PM' to TIMESTAMP format with below command.

select 'Jan 15 2019 6:57PM'::TIMESTAMP;

Is there any way to do this? The date and time can be either single or double digit and even time of the day can be either AM or PM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this one?

```
select to_timestamp('Jan 15 2019 6:57PM','MON DD YYYY HH12:MIAM');

+------------------------------------------------------------+
| TO_TIMESTAMP('JAN 15 2019 6:57PM','MON DD YYYY HH12:MIAM') |
+------------------------------------------------------------+
| 2019-01-15 18:57:00.000                                    |
+------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks @Gokhan. Yes this is working for both single and double digit time but when date become smaller than 10 like 'JAN 9 2019 6:57PM', then it is failing. Is there any generalised version for all possibilities?

Comment: @SayantanMandal What do you mean?  Same code works for the Jan 9 date, as well.  `select to_timestamp('Jan 9 2019 6:57PM','MON DD YYYY HH12:MIAM');`

Comment: Apologies, my bad. I used a different format. Thanks @MikeWalton for this clarification.